# How to randomize the seed-number in Modelsim?

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, verification, random-number, questasim

In *EDA-Playground*, I know that we use **+ntb_random_seed_automatic** to randomize the seed number. However, I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that in **Modelsim** so that I have a random seed number.

I was wondering if **Modelsim** has the similar automatic seed number option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SystemVerilog, use the flag: `-sv_seed random` along with `vsim` command  for ModelSim and QuestaSim.

Comment: Thank you very much, Is it possible to make the **Modelsim** automatically add `-sv_seed random` with `vsim/restart` commands?

Comment: We have to manually set the flag. Use transcript or do or tcl file for simulation instead of GUI. I don't think there's any option in the tool to make it automatic. @Taher

Comment: Note that `restart` command doesn't support vsim flags as per tool manual.